# What does $\mathbb{E}_{t-2}$ mean when calculating mean/expected value?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, conditional-expectation

*For 4 coin tosses represented here as a moving average of my last 4 tosses.* A win represented by the arbitrary side of the coin represented **1**, a loss the other side represented by an outcome of **0**.

Given $\epsilon_{t-3}\ =\ \epsilon_{t-2} = 1$

**Mean:** conditional on above information

$$\mathbb{E}(w_t\ | \epsilon_{t-3} = \epsilon_{t-2}= 1) = 1/4 \epsilon_t + 1/4\epsilon_{t-1} + 1/4\epsilon_{t-2} + 1/4 \epsilon_{t-3})$$

Since the 3rd and 2nd error are given a value of 1, the conditional expectation of $w_t$ is

$\mathbb{E}_{t-2}*w_t=\mathbb{E}(w_t\ | \epsilon_{t-3} = \epsilon_{t-2}= 1) = (1/4)(\mathbb{E}_{t-2}\epsilon_t + \mathbb{E}_{t-2}\epsilon_{t-1} + \mathbb{E}_{t-2}\epsilon_{t-2} + \mathbb{E}_{t-2}\epsilon_{t-3}$

$\mathbb{E}_{t-2} = 0.25(0 + 0+1+1) = 0.5$

I come about the same answer and it's an easy one. But I'm confused as the formal evaluation. In the example above copied from text, why is there an expectation at t-2? I'm not at all familiar with the notation $\mathbb{E}_{t-2}$and it seems everything in the final equation is converted to that. What does it mean? I'm coming about the same result so I'm not sure how much attention I should be giving this?

Comment: It would just be the expectation 2 steps before the current time?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be intuitively. But why add it? It doesn't seem to change anything so it's got me hung up on why?

Comment: Perhaps for consistency when dependence structures of error terms matter. Like flipping a coin is clearly independent of what you flipped before. But if say one flips a coin at t-2 and then if the result is a 1, they flip double the coins at t-1 or the result is a 0, they flip 1 coin, there is a dependence structure base on a prior outcome.

Comment: If that's the case, @TonyHellmuth wouldn't t-2 represent the second to last throw? If 4 were thrown and it starts at $\epsilon_{t-3}$ as you see in the weighted average equation. Then $\epsilon_{t-3}$ is the first of the four tosses in time. $\epsilon_{t-2}$ then being 3rd.. etc